# Is it possible to enforce XAML coding guidelines?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

Is it possible to enforce XAML coding guidelines?

For example, StyleCop can be set to throw errors if the rules are not respected, but as far as I know this doesn't work with XAML, StyleCop only analyzes C# source code.

Is there a tool or a check-in policy that enforces XAML coding guidelines?

Thanks !

Comment: What kind of guidelines do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

[Resharper might have what you are looking for.](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/xaml_editor.html)

I haven't done xaml work since upgrading to version 6, so I haven't any personal experience on it.

Comment: Thanks, I know about R#, but it doesn't enforce you to code in a specific way, like StyleCop does, R# only gives you some suggestions on how it should look like. What I need is to enforce this suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Xaml Styler (VS extension). You can download it directly from vs. Also, there are some other powerful extensions for this purpose like Code maid. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft XAML Toolkit has FxCop Integration

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/XAML